# Google line charts não aparece a linha

Tags: php, google-charts

Estou tentando gerar um gráfico de linha como o Google charts mas as linhas não se formam e não sei o motivo. O gráfico até aparece com as legendas mais não funciona segue abaixo o meu código (o botão que chama o gráfico):

```
    $("#config2").on("click", function() {
$("#f").val("2");

google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart']});

   function drawChart() {
        var i = $("#i2").val();
        var m = $("#in").val();
        var d = $("#te").val();
        var f = $("#f").val();

                // call ajax function to get sports data
                var jsonData = $.ajax({
                    url: "dadosestatistica.php",
                    type: 'GET',
                    dataType: "json",
                    data : {i: i, m: m, d: d, f: f},
                    async: false
                }).responseText;


                //The DataTable object is used to hold the data passed into a visualization.
                var data = new google.visualization.DataTable(jsonData);

                var options = {
                    chart: {
                      title: 'Gráfico de Crimes Estado Rio de Janeiro'
                    }
                  };
                    // To render the pie chart.
                var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));


                chart.draw(data, options);


            }


            // Set a callback to run when the Google Visualization API is loaded.
            google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);


});
```

Os dados da estatística que gera o array:

```
$data = "";
            $rows = array();
            $retorno = array();
            $retorno['cols'] = array(
            array('label' => 'DATA', 'type' => 'string'),
            array('label' => 'VALOR1', 'type' => 'number'),
            array('label' => 'VALOR2', 'type' => 'number'),
            array('label' => 'VALOR3', 'type' => 'number'),
            array('label' => 'VALOR4', 'type' => 'number'),
            array('label' => 'VALOR5', 'type' => 'number'),
            array('label' => 'VALOR6', 'type' => 'number'),
            array('label' => 'VALOR7', 'type' => 'number'),
            array('label' => 'VALOR8', 'type' => 'number'),
            );

            while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res)) {

            $temp = array();

            if($data != $row['data']){
                $data = $row['data'];

            $temp[] = array('v' => (string)converte_data($row['data']));                

            }
            $temp[] = array('v' => (int)$row['total']);
            $rows[] = array('c' => $temp);          
            }

            $retorno['rows'] = $rows;
            $jsonTable = json_encode($retorno);

            echo $jsonTable;
```

Saída do array:

```
{"cols":[
{"label":"DATA","type":"string"},
{"label":"VALOR1","type":"number"},
{"label":"VALOR2","type":"number"},
{"label":"VALOR3","type":"number"},
{"label":"VALOR4","type":"number"},
{"label":"VALOR5","type":"number"},
{"label":"VALOR6","type":"number"},
{"label":"VALOR7","type":"number"},
{"label":"VALOR8","type":"number"}
],
"rows":[
{"c":[{"v":"30\/10\/2017"},{"v":1}]},{"c":[{"v":3}]},{"c":[{"v":1}]},{"c":[{"v":1}]},{"c":[{"v":1}]},{"c":[{"v":4}]},{"c":[{"v":1}]},{"c":[{"v":4}]}
]
}
```

Já quebrei a cabeça e não consigo saber como resolver, desde já agradeço qualquer ajuda.

Descobri o motivo de não estar funcionando o array deve ser montado dessa maneira:

```
{"cols":[
    {"label":"DATA","type":"string"},
    {"label":"VALOR1","type":"number"},
    {"label":"VALOR2","type":"number"},
    {"label":"VALOR3","type":"number"},
    {"label":"VALOR4","type":"number"},
    {"label":"VALOR5","type":"number"},
    {"label":"VALOR6","type":"number"},
    {"label":"VALOR7","type":"number"},
    {"label":"VALOR8","type":"number"}
    ],
    "rows":[
    {"c":[{"v":"30\/10\/2017"},{"v":1},{"v":3},{"v":1},{"v":1},{"v":1},{"v":4},{"v":1},{"v":4}]},
    {"c":[{"v":"31\/10\/2017"},{"v":2},{"v":4},{"v":3},{"v":2},{"v":4},{"v":3},{"v":2},{"v":5}]}
    ]
    }
```

Toda vez que muda a data é uma nova linha os dados do banco vem assim:

```
'VALOR1', '2017-10-30', '1'
'VALOR2', '2017-10-30', '3'
'VALOR3', '2017-10-30', '1'
'VALOR4', '2017-10-30', '1'
'VALOR5', '2017-10-30', '1'
'VALOR6', '2017-10-30', '4'
'VALOR7', '2017-10-30', '1'
'VALOR8', '2017-10-30', '4'
'VALOR1', '2017-10-31', '2'
'VALOR2', '2017-10-31', '4'
'VALOR3', '2017-10-31', '3'
'VALOR4', '2017-10-31', '2'
'VALOR5', '2017-10-31', '4'
'VALOR6', '2017-10-31', '3'
'VALOR7', '2017-10-31', '2'
'VALOR8', '2017-10-31', '5'
```

Não estou conseguindo montar esse array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolvi o problema mudando o sql para que a resposta do banco viesse dessa maneira:

```
'DATA', 'VALOR1', 'VALOR2', 'VALOR3', 'VALOR4', 'VALOR5', 'VALOR6', 'VALOR7', 'VALOR8'  
'2017-10-30', '1', '3', '1', '1', '1', '4', '1', '4'
'2017-10-31', '2', '4', '3', '2', '4', '3', '2', '5'
```

e o loop que monta o array mudei para:

```
  while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res)) {

            $temp = array();           

            $temp[] = array('v' => (string)converte_data($row['data']));        
            $temp[] = array('v' => (int)$row['valor1']);
            $temp[] = array('v' => (int)$row['valor2']);
            $temp[] = array('v' => (int)$row['valor3']);
            $temp[] = array('v' => (int)$row['valor4']);
            $temp[] = array('v' => (int)$row['valor5']);
            $temp[] = array('v' => (int)$row['valor6']);
            $temp[] = array('v' => (int)$row['valor7']);
            $temp[] = array('v' => (int)$row['valor8']);
            $rows[] = array('c' => $temp);          
            }
```